# how to set architecture when building multi-arch Docker image?

Tags: docker, multiarch

Let's say I have an app `foo` built for many different arches (e.g, `foo-arm64`, `foo-amd64`, etc).  I would like to make very small Docker images like so:

```
FROM scratch

ARG ARCH
ADD foo-$ARCH /bin/foo

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/foo" ]
```

However, when I build an image:

```
docker build -t foo:arm64 --platform linux/arm64 --build-arg ARCH=arm64 .
```

the architecture isn't correct:

```
docker inspect foo:arm64 | grep Arch
        "Architecture": "amd64",              # should be arm64??
```

The image arch seems to always come from the host.  How can I build a Docker image with the right architecture when that differs from the host?  How do the official Docker images do this?

Comment: On which platform you have created docker image?

Comment: I'm running the build on an `amd64` server and am trying to create images for `amd64`, `arm64v8`, `arm32v7`, and `ppc64le`

Answer (score 2):

Use **docker buildx** command instead of **docker build -t** command.
Docker build only create docker image with respective platform.

For more information refer documentation : https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/